# Send an email with python does not work

Tags: python, smtp

I try to send an email via python.
According to my script the sending was successfull.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['my@emailadress.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 1025)
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

But when I check my emails, I got no new mails. :(
Where is the problem? Where is my sent email?

**Edit:**

My smtp test server are:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        return

server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)
print "Started...."

asyncore.loop()
```

And my smtp Server says:

```
Receiving message from: ('127.0.0.1', 65071)
Message addressed from: from@fromdomain.com
Message addressed to  : ['my@emailadress.com']
Message length        : 129
```

Comment: Is the SMTP server on localhost working? Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: What's running on port 1025 on localhost?  Does it have a log file?

Comment: I think you need a listener on port 1025 to receive this email. If the listener is not listening, I get similar or the same problems.

Comment: I does not need a login. Look at my smtp-server implementation. (I edited my start post)

I checked also the spam folder. No email :(

Comment: Your `CustomSMTPServer` works, true. But does your SMTP server that your *really* try to use for email sending? What does its logfiles say?

Comment: Your SMTP server doesn't actually relay messages, it just prints some stuff. Why are you expecting the message to appear in some inbox somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process_message()` does nothing but output its input data. So it displays data about the mail it got, but it doesn't forward this mail to your real inbox, but drops the data.

So it is normal that you don't get the mail.

Comment: The superclass just raises `NotImplementedError`; the class probably needs to inherit from `PureProxy` or `MailmanProxy` as well for this to work.

Comment: You are right. I completely misunderstood the question...

Comment: That means I need a smtp-MAIL-server? But where can I get a test-mailserver to check my mail sending?

Comment: You could either set up a postfox or something, you could enter the connection data of a "real" mail server, or you could enhance your `process_message()` to do whatever it is intended to do...